# What is the most efficient way to find the first matching record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For instance, user = find the first Fred from a list of users

Comment: what do you mean by **first Fred**? is that, there are many `Fred` in user list and have to find that `Fred` who signed up first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`User.find_by(first_name: 'Fred') # it finds the first user` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by

Comment: It depends on what you mean by first, but yeah, this is the most performant method. If you care about ordering you should use `first`. I explain it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If your want order by and pick the first record in the ordered result, following also should work:

```
user = User.where(:name => "Fred").order(:age).first
```

Answer (score 1):

The most performant way is to use `find_by`:

```rb
User.find_by(name: 'Fred')
```

This method has been added on Rails 4 and it is defined like this:

```rb
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
end
```

In further details, `take` differs from `first` regarding the order. `first` will return the first record after reordering your records based on the primary key while `take` will return whatever it finds first.

So while using `where().take` is equivalent to `find_by` and choosing whether to use one of the other is a matter of taste, `where().first` differs from `find_by` in a subtle and not so obvious way.

> *source: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rails-style-guide/issues/76*

Answer (score 0):

If you access User model with find or where commands. It will always give you the first entry sorted by created_at. You can always sort the data depending on parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find_by as follows

```
   User.find_by_first_name('Fred')
```

Obviously, it give first user of Fred